# PHP Ping no response

Tags: php, laravel, ping, valet

I'm running a local dev environment using larval valet on my Mac.
And I'm trying to ping a host, however I never get a response.

Running a simple shell command like "ls" works and gives the expected output.

**Code**

```
function getStatus($name) {
    $ip =   "1.1.1.1";
    exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $output, $status);
    print_r($output);
    print_r($status);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( ) 127
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ping runs in an endless loop on *NIX systems you have to limit the number of pings that it executes. I suspect you tried to do that with the `-n` param, however, the proper one for this would be `-c` which stands for "count".

Therefore you should exec the ping like so:

```php
exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $output, $status);
```

And it works fine:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    [1] => 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=8.71 ms
    [2] => 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=8.71 ms
    [3] => 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=8.82 ms
    [4] =>
    [5] => --- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
    [6] => 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
    [7] => rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.713/8.751/8.824/0.119 ms
)
```

Side note:
The `-n` parameter exists as well but just instructs ping to only accept numeric input - IP addresses and not hostnames.

From the man page: https://ss64.com/osx/ping.html

```
-n         Numeric output only. No attempt will be made to lookup symbolic
           names for host addresses.
```